# Loop a code n times in javascript, n determined by user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, input

I'm trying to offer a text box in which the user can enter the size of the array to create, hit submit, then a prompt will appear that many times, each time asking for an integer to put in the array.

This is what I have so far:

http://codepen.io/sharryliang0730/pen/pRMqOm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
             }

function yesnoCheck() {
if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
} 
else if(document.getElementById('noCheck').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
   }
}


            var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.onclick = function() {
getTheData() ;
}



function getTheData() {
   var sizeInput = document.getElementById("sizeInput");
   var inputValues = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < sizeInput; i++){
    inputValues.push(prompt('Enter the value'));

     }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Please choose what you wanna do:<br>

<input type="button" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck" value="Create Array"/>


<input type="button" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"value="Search Array"/>


<br>
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
<br> Please input the size of the array.<br><br>
<input type="text" class="sizeInput" id="sizeInput" /> <br/><br>
<input type="button" name="submit"    id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>


<div id="ifNo" style="display:none">

<div id="showInputValues">
</div>
```

EDIT: I added in the suggested code, but it is still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: So where is the prompt?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. I do not know how to set it up so that the prompt will show up and loop for however many times the user input for it.

Or do you mean the prompt asking for the size of the array, before the loop? I used input type=text instead of a new window prompt. Does that affect things?

Answer (score 1):

Your inputValues is empty. You need to add this:

```
    var inputValues = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < sizeInput; i++)
    {
        inputValues.push(prompt('Enter the value'));

    }
```

it gives you an array like this: ["1", "2", "3"]

But if you want your array has int values do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        inputValues.push(parseInt(prompt('Enter the value')));//[1,2,3]
    }
```

By your explanations `var sizeInput = document.getElementById("sizeInput");`

sizeInput is a number that user entered. If it is for example 5 and you want the array has [0,1,2,3,4] you need to do this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < sizeInput; i++)
  {
    inputValues.push(i);
  }
```

You have many problems in your code, I edited all in code snippet below:

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
            var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
            submit.onclick = function ()
            {
                getTheData();
            }
        }

        function yesnoCheck()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').onclick)
            {
                document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('noCheck').onclick)
            {
                document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        function getTheData()
        {
            var sizeInput = document.getElementById("sizeInput").value;
            var inputValues = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < sizeInput; i++)
            {
                inputValues.push(prompt('Enter the value'));

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Please choose what you wanna do:<br>

    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck" value="Create Array" />


    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck" value="Search Array" />


    <br>
    <div id="ifYes" style="display: none">
        <br>
        Please input the size of the array.<br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="sizeInput" id="sizeInput" />
        <br />
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: loopFunction();" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>


    <div id="ifNo" style="display: none"></div>

    <div id="showInputValues">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I updated my code, but it is not showing up the prompts... I have a feeling it is something about my sizeInput that is causing it not to work...

Comment: I added a code snippet with some edits in your code. Please look and let me know the result.

Comment: I noticed you moved the submit information into the first function, added ".value", and added "onclick="javascript: loopFunction();" to the html. If you don't mind explaining, why is that? Especially with the onclick. I thought having it in the script was enough. Thank you again. I definitely have more I need to research about js!

Comment: I did not add `javascript: loopFunction();` to html, and I do not know what is this. In the js cod you have not any function named `loopFunction`.